# Best database & schema for a tree?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database-design, database

What database (and schema, if applicable) would be most appropriate for storing and retrieving data (location, timestamp) that can be placed at any node of an arbitrarily defined tree? For instance: the location of a book you own:

```
                                     Book
                          |                          |
                         Home                       Work
                  |     |        |                |         | 
              Bedroom   Bathroom  Den           Office     Conf room
               |    |             |    |          |
              Closet Underbed    EntCtr Closet    Desk 
           |      |
       Top Shelf  Bottom Shelf
          XXXX
```

For each item record, the item's position could look conceivably different but likely the same root and primary nodes, but beyond that could have a different branches and leaves where the item is actually located. And with each added item, the tree itself could conceivably grow (you could add specificity to that "top shelf in the bedroom closet" node eventually, placing newer items in one of 2-3 sub-locations).

I'm thinking a SQL db might not be ideal since the tree could expand arbitrarily and could be entirely different depending on user, but not sure how a NoSQL db like Mongo could handle any updating/expansion (like if the example book is moved from an existing node to a new one a level or two deeper). Maybe the depth/breadth of tree levels could be constrained if using a SQL db, but the column labels could vary, and on the other hand Mongo could simply create a new document for an item if it is moved to a new location.

Any insights from database experts very much appreciated!

Comment: You can absolutely represent a tree in a relational database, however there are a number of different ways to do so, each with different trade-offs.  Without more details of exactly what queries and transformations you intend to make, it's impossible to answer which is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "SQL DB" I think you are referencing a ***relational database***. For this you seem to want a ***hierarchical database***. You can get such a structure in a relational DB. It's called a **Nested Set Model**. See: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 2):

Locations, especially those managed by different organizations, are not necessarily hierarchical. For example, Russia is in Europe and Asia. Texarkana is in Texas and Arkansas. US ZIP 42223 is [in Kentucky and Tennessee](https://www.google.ca/maps/search/42223/@36.6409484,-87.4465687,14z). Geopolitical locations are graphical / networked.

That being said, you can easily model hierarchical data in a SQL database by using an adjacency list:

```
create table locations (
  location_id int primary key,
  name text not null,
  parent_id int null references locations(location_id)
);
```

You can then query such a table using Recursive Common Table Expressions (CTEs), which are available in every major database **except MySQL**, but it sounds like switching databases is an option for you.

Here's an example: http://blog.databasepatterns.com/2014/02/trees-paths-recursive-cte-postgresql.html

You don't need Nested Set, Materialized Path or Closure Table if your DB supports RCTE.